# AG Grid Server-side model- What is the maximum number of records that can be rendered in the server side ag grid model?

Tags: server, ag-grid

AG Grid  Server-side model- What is the maximum number of records that can be rendered in the server side ag grid model? We are facing intermittent browser crash issue when we tried to render 10000 records in a grid

Answer (score 1):

There really should be no limit.
The whole point of the server-side model is that only the rows that are being shown in the viewport (plus a small buffer) should be held on the client-side at any one time.
As the user scrolls (or pages), the grid 'throws away' the rows that are no longer shown,
and replaces them with rows from the server.

Comment: is that we get ? tree data structure on server side